# How to generate or create data url for MIME type application/pdf in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, data-uri

I upload a attachment and when I click on the attachment, The attachment should open in a new tab, The problem is how to obtain data URL, theMIME type is application/pdf. and this i am trying to obatin the

url "data:application/pdf,base64,data"
I am converting the data to base64 using

`let encodedString = btoa('' + attachment.data);`

```
<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,encodedString "></iframe>
```

since attachment.data is of type Blob, so i am using "('' +)" this to convert to string and i get the encoded value,

but i get this warnig in Google chrome console "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf:"

so can some please tell me how to do it I am new to this.

Comment: If your data is type of `Blob`, you might want to convert it to base64 first. using [`FileReader.readAsDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL).

Comment: @Terry I used FileReader.readAsDataURL(attachment.data) i get this error Argument of type 'Blob | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Blob'.
  Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'Blob'.
    Property 'size' is missing in type 'ArrayBuffer'.